# Pyqt: How to get a signal that QLineEdit is on focus?

Tags: events, pyqt, focus

This specific window has 2 QLineEdits: one called "User" and the other called "Password". Below them there is a keyboard created with many QPushButtons. Now, I have to tell the method connected to those buttons to print the respective letter or number in the selected QLineEdit and I'm having a hard time getting the signal for which QLineEdit is selected at the moment.

How do I do I get that signal? The application starts with "User" focused: `self.User.setFocus()`

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the buttons will gain focus when you click them.  You can change this by setting their focus policy to `NoFocus`.  This way, your lineedits won't lose focus when users click the buttons.

```
 button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
```

As long as the lineedit had focus when the button was clicked, you can get the focused widget in your button handler like this:

```
lineedit = QtGui.QApplication.focusWidget()
```

You could check to make sure the focused widget is one of the two lineedit widgets and then update their text accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. With `lineedit = QtGui.QApplication.focusWidget()` I get: `<PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit object at 0x746e6df0>`, from this how can I get the object's name?

Comment: Oh, I got it, is as simple as adding `.objectName()` to the line, as in `lineedit = QtGui.QApplication.focusWidget().objectName()`